# Detect fitness machine mechanically folded in a certain position

Tags: microcontroller, proximity-sensor

I am developing a controller for a multi-use fitness machine that can be folded/unfolded, somewhat like a foldable bike. It means that after folded, it will stay in that configuration for a long time. What would be the best way for the MCU to detect folding/unfolding in a certain configuration? I can imagine something like a simple button that is pressed when foldable parts touch each other but that doesn't seem to be mechanically reliable. Is Hall sensor a better way to do this?

Comment: A potentiometer, a rotary (absolute) encoder, microswitches.

Answer (score 1):

Microlever limit switch should be plenty reliable.

Omron:
[image]

E-Switch:
[image]

Or magnet and on/off hall sensor IC.

Comment: Optical reflectors are very reliable too with no moving parts except the DUT.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yeah I had considered adding those but decided it was a little overblown.